# Who had the most simultaneous Billboard top 10 singles before Taylor Swift?

Tags: album, billboard

Taylor Swift made history with her October 21, 2022 release of *Midnights* when the top ten songs in Billboard's Hot 100 were all from her album.

Who held the record previously?

Comment: This type of 'hit measurement' just hurts my OCD. New album comes out, fans listen to it a lot… all of it. This results in all tracks from it being considered as 'singles' & just skews the measurement. Back in the day, people would have had to go out & buy ten little bits of plastic to generate this data, not just stream it on spotify etc. Compare to the Beatles in 64, when they had the top five simultaneously. People had to go out & buy 5 individual pieces of plastic. Other tracks on the same album could not even be considered. They were not available individually.

Comment: @Tetsujin if you count B sides, five pieces of plastic usually implies ten distinct songs.

Comment: @phoog - B-sides were often not album tracks too. That doesn't chance my basic statement, that if a track was not available individually as an A-side, it could never chart.

Comment: @Tetsujin and rightly so.  I wonder how many people bought _Can't Buy Me Love_ because they wanted to own _You Can't Do That._  Not many, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drake previously held the record with nine singles from *Certified Lover Boy* in September 2021.

> Swift surpasses Drake, who logged nine of the Hot 100’s top 10 for a week in September 2021....

> Plus, *Midnights* becomes the first album ever with as many as 10 Hot 100 top 10s, besting the nine from Drake’s *Certified Lover Boy* in 2021.

(SOURCE: [Taylor Swift Makes History as First Artist With Entire Top 10 on Billboard Hot 100, Led by ‘Anti-Hero’ at No. 1](https://www.billboard.com/music/chart-beat/taylor-swift-all-hot-100-top-10-anti-hero-1235163664/))